# Eager query in a lazy relation?

Tags: java, jpa, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have an entity with lazy relations like this:

```
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_entity", sequenceName = "seq_entity", allocationSize = 1)
@DynamicUpdate
public class Entity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_entity")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_entity")
    private Long id;

    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_relation1")
    private Relation1 relation1;

    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_relation2")
    private Relation2 relation2;

    // ...
}
```

When I make a query to load the other relations I have to specify them like:

`return jpaQuery()
    .select(qEntity)
    .distinct()
    .from(qEntity)
    .innerJoin(qEntity.relation1).fetchJoin()
    .leftJoin(qEntity.relation2).fetchJoin()
    .fetch();`

But I want to load them without specify into left joins and inner joins for one query...
There is a way to load all in eager mode for one query? Is it possible to desactivate the `FetchType.LAZY` for one query?

I am thinking in something like

`return jpaQuery()
    .select(qEntity)
    .distinct()
    .from(qEntity)
    .fetchEager();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use entity graph for that. It will be something like this:

```
EntityGraph<Post> entityGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(YourEntity.class);
entityGraph.addAttributeNodes("relation1");
entityGraph.addAttributeNodes("relation2");
```

And in query

```
TypedQuery<Post> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
typedQuery.setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", entityGraph);
Post post = typedQuery.getSingleResult();
```

This can be enclosed with named entity graph (over entity)

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
  name = "entity-with-all-relations",
  attributeNodes = {
    @NamedAttributeNode("relation1"),
    @NamedAttributeNode("relation2"),
  },
```

thus reused many times. To do that, you use `EntityManager#getEntityGraph`

Comment: I thought about and in _my case_ it's better to separate them in queries, but your answer should help others in this specific case. thanks